# how to increase performance of game?

Tags: javascript, android, performance

I have to build an android application game.

Previously, I tried to build it with pixi.JS but it doesn't work very good on Canvas for Android..

I'm actually trying to build it with CollieJS, and i've a simple example here :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var stats = new Stats();
        stats.setMode(0); // 0: fps, 1: ms

        // Align top-left
        stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
        stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';

        document.body.appendChild( stats.domElement );

        setInterval( function () {

          stats.begin();

          stats.end();

    }, 1000 / 60 );

        //Creation calque
        var layer = new collie.Layer({
            width: 1280,
            height: 700
        });

        var score = 0;
        var thisManyDb=10;
        var comboCounter=0;
        function letWinSomePoints(){
            score+=thisManyDb;
            comboCounter++;
            txt_score.text(score+"dB");
            txt_ComboCounter.text("Combo: "+comboCounter);
        };

        //Chargement de la planche
        collie.ImageManager.add({
            sprite_bassiste: "assets/img/spriteBass2.png",
            sprite_batteur: "assets/img/spriteDrummer2.png",
            sprite_guitF: "assets/img/spriteGuitF2.png",
            sprite_guitH: "assets/img/spriteGuitH.png"
        });

        //Découpage de la planche
        collie.ImageManager.addSprite(
            "sprite_bassiste", {
                normal:[0,0,187,268,3],
                normal_rose:[561,0,186,268,3],
                normal_click:[0,268,264,394,3],
                occupe:[0,662,215,283,3],
                occupe_rose:[645,662,215,283,3],
                occupe_rouge:[0,945,215,283,3],
                combo:[0,1223,277,309,3]
            }
        );
        collie.ImageManager.addSprite(
            "sprite_batteur", {
                normal:[0,0,297,297,3],
                normal_rose:[891,0,297,295,3],
                normal_click:[0,297,273,376,3],
                occupe:[819,339,356,334,3],
                occupe_rose:[0,662,356,334,3],
                occupe_rouge:[1068,662,356,334,3],
                combo:[0,1007,297,306,3]
            }
        );
        collie.ImageManager.addSprite(
            "sprite_guitF", {
                normal:[0,0,216,265,3],
                normal_rose:[648,0,216,265,3],
                normal_click:[0,265,351,372,3],
                occupe:[0,637,216,265,3],
                occupe_rose:[648,637,216,265,3],
                occupe_rouge:[0,902,216,265,3],
                combo:[0,1167,281,309,3]
            }
        );
        collie.ImageManager.addSprite(
            "sprite_guitH", {
                normal:[0,0,174,219,3],
                normal_rose:[522,0,174,279,3],
                occupe:[0,280,269,256,3],
                occupe_rose:[0,535,269,256,3],
                occupe_rouge:[0,791,269,256,3],
                normal_click:[0,1047,309,376,3],
                combo:[0,1423,283,309,3]
            }
        );

        //Creation d'un objet
        var bassiste = new collie.DisplayObject({
            width: 187,
            height: 268,
            y:0,
            x:0,
            backgroundImage: "sprite_bassiste",
            spriteSheet : "normal",
            set_normal:function(){
                bassiste.set("spriteSheet", "normal");
                bassiste._htOption.height=268;
                bassiste._htOption.width=187;
                bassiste._htOption.x=0;
                bassiste._htOption.y=0;
            },
            set_occupe:function(){
                bassiste.set("spriteSheet", "occupe");
                bassiste._htOption.height=283;
                bassiste._htOption.width=215;
                bassiste._htOption.x-15;//(-15)
                bassiste._htOption.y=2;//(+2)
            },
            set_occupe_rose:function(){
                bassiste.set("spriteSheet", "occupe_rose");
                bassiste._htOption.height=283;
                bassiste._htOption.width=215;
                bassiste._htOption.x-15;//(-15)
                bassiste._htOption.y=2;//(+2)
            },
            set_combo:function(){
                bassiste.set("spriteSheet", "combo");
                bassiste._htOption.height=309;
                bassiste._htOption.width=277;
                bassiste._htOption.x-40;//(-40)
                bassiste._htOption.y-20;//(+20)
            },
            }).attach({
                click: function (e){
                    if (bassiste.get("spriteSheet")=="normal_rose" && has_been_clicked==false) {
                        has_been_clicked=true;
                        bassiste.set("spriteSheet", "normal_click");
                        bassiste._htOption.height=394;
                        bassiste._htOption.width=264;
                        bassiste._htOption.x-=55;//(-40)
                        bassiste._htOption.y-=126;//(-126)
                        letWinSomePoints();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            bassiste._htOption.set_normal();
                            has_been_clicked=false;
                        },500);
                    };
                }
            }).addTo(layer);
        var batteur = new collie.DisplayObject({
            x:187,
            y:0,
            width: 297,
            height: 297,
            backgroundImage: "sprite_batteur",
            spriteSheet : "normal",
            set_normal:function(){
                batteur.set("spriteSheet", "normal");
                batteur._htOption.height=297;
                batteur._htOption.width=297;
                batteur._htOption.x=187;
                batteur._htOption.y=0;
            },
            set_occupe:function(){
                batteur.set("spriteSheet", "occupe");
                batteur._htOption.height=334;
                batteur._htOption.width=356;
                batteur._htOption.x-=73;//-73
                batteur._htOption.y-=39;//-39
            },
            set_occupe_rose:function(){
                batteur.set("spriteSheet", "occupe_rose");
                batteur._htOption.height=334;
                batteur._htOption.width=356;
                batteur._htOption.x-=73;//-73
                batteur._htOption.y-=39;//-39
            },
            set_combo:function(){
                batteur.set("spriteSheet", "combo");
                batteur._htOption.height=306;
                batteur._htOption.width=297;
                batteur._htOption.x=187;//pas de modifs position
                batteur._htOption.y=0;
            },
            }).attach({
                click: function (e){
                    if (batteur.get("spriteSheet")=="normal_rose" && has_been_clicked==false) {
                        has_been_clicked=true;
                        batteur.set("spriteSheet", "normal_click");
                        batteur._htOption.height=376;
                        batteur._htOption.width=273;
                        batteur._htOption.y-=84;//-84
                        batteur._htOption.x+=16;//+16
                        letWinSomePoints();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            batteur._htOption.set_normal();
                            has_been_clicked=false;
                        },500);
                    };
                }
            }).addTo(layer);
        var guitF = new collie.DisplayObject({
            x:187+297,
            y:0,
            width: 216,
            height: 265,
            backgroundImage: "sprite_guitF",
            spriteSheet : "normal",
            set_normal:function(){
                guitF.set("spriteSheet", "normal");
                guitF._htOption.height=265;
                guitF._htOption.width=216;
                guitF._htOption.x=187+297;
                guitF._htOption.y=0;
            },
            set_occupe:function(){
                guitF.set("spriteSheet", "occupe");
                guitF._htOption.height=265;
                guitF._htOption.width=216;
                guitF._htOption.x+=21;//+21
            },
            set_occupe_rose:function(){
                guitF.set("spriteSheet", "occupe_rose");
                guitF._htOption.height=265;
                guitF._htOption.width=216;
                guitF._htOption.x+=21;//+21
            },
            set_combo:function(){
                guitF.set("spriteSheet", "combo");
                guitF._htOption.height=309;
                guitF._htOption.width=281;
                guitF._htOption.x-=32;//+32
                guitF._htOption.y-=44;//+44
            },
            }).attach({
                click: function (e){
                    if (guitF.get("spriteSheet")=="normal_rose" && has_been_clicked==false) {
                        has_been_clicked=true;
                        guitF.set("spriteSheet", "normal_click");
                        guitF._htOption.height=372;
                        guitF._htOption.width=351;
                        guitF._htOption.y-=96;//-96
                        guitF._htOption.x-=67;//-67
                        letWinSomePoints();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            guitF._htOption.set_normal();
                            has_been_clicked=false;
                        },500);
                    };
                }
            }).addTo(layer);
        var guitH = new collie.DisplayObject({
            x:187+297+216,
            y:0,
            width: 174,
            height: 279,
            backgroundImage: "sprite_guitH",
            spriteSheet : "normal",
            set_normal:function(){
                guitH.set("spriteSheet", "normal");
                guitH._htOption.height=279;
                guitH._htOption.width=174;
                guitH._htOption.x=187+297+216;
                guitH._htOption.y=0;
            },
            set_occupe:function(){
                guitH.set("spriteSheet", "occupe");
                guitH._htOption.height=256;
                guitH._htOption.width=269;
                guitH._htOption.x-=19;//-19
                guitH._htOption.y+=12;//+12
            },
            set_occupe_rose:function(){
                guitH.set("spriteSheet", "occupe_rose");
                guitH._htOption.height=256;
                guitH._htOption.width=269;
                guitH._htOption.x-=19;//-19
                guitH._htOption.y+=12;//+12
            },
            set_combo:function(){
                guitH.set("spriteSheet", "combo");
                guitH._htOption.height=309;
                guitH._htOption.width=283;
                guitH._htOption.x-=71;//-71
                guitH._htOption.y+=22;//+22
            },
            }).attach({
                click: function (e){
                    if (guitH.get("spriteSheet")=="normal_rose" && has_been_clicked==false) {
                        has_been_clicked=true;
                        guitH.set("spriteSheet", "normal_click");
                        guitH._htOption.y-=76;//76
                        guitH._htOption.x-=102;//102
                        guitH._htOption.height=376;
                        guitH._htOption.width=309;
                        letWinSomePoints();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            guitH._htOption.set_normal();
                            has_been_clicked=false;
                        },500);
                    };
                }
            }).addTo(layer);
        var txt_score = new collie.Text({
            width : 100,
            height : 100,
            x : 0,
            y : 0,
            fontColor : "#000000"
        }).text(score+"dB").addTo(layer);

        var txt_DbCounter = new collie.Text({
            width : 100,
            height : 100,
            x : 100,
            y : 0,
            fontColor : "#000000"
        }).text('').addTo(layer);

        var txt_ComboCounter = new collie.Text({
            width : 100,
            height : 100,
            x : 200,
            y : 0,
            fontColor : "#000000"
        }).addTo(layer);

        //Définition de l'anim du sprite
        var timer = collie.Timer.cycle(
            bassiste, "10fps", {
            from:0,
            to:2,
            }
        );
        collie.Timer.cycle(
            batteur, "10fps", {
            from: 0,
            to: 2,
            }
        );
        collie.Timer.cycle(
            guitF, "10fps", {
            from: 0,
            to: 2,
            }
        );
        collie.Timer.cycle(
            guitH, "10fps", {
            from: 0,
            to: 2,
            }
        );

        var choosen_musician = 0;
        var busy_musican = 0;
        var trap_musician = 0;
        var has_been_clicked = false;

        // Fonction boucle intégrée dans collie
        collie.Timer.repeat(function () {
            //Pioche un musicien
            choosen_musician=Math.round(Math.random()*3);
            busy_musican  = Math.round(Math.random()*10);
            trap_musician  = Math.round(Math.random()*20);

            if (busy_musican==0 && busy_musican!=choosen_musician) {
                busy_musican=bassiste;
            } else if (busy_musican==1 && busy_musican!=choosen_musician){
                busy_musican=batteur;
            } else if (busy_musican==2 && busy_musican!=choosen_musician){
                busy_musican=guitF;
            } else if (busy_musican==3 && busy_musican!=choosen_musician){
                busy_musican=guitH;
            };

            if (choosen_musician==0) {
                choosen_musician=bassiste;
            } else if (choosen_musician==1){
                choosen_musician=batteur;
            } else if (choosen_musician==2){
                choosen_musician=guitF;
            } else if (choosen_musician==3){
                choosen_musician=guitH;
            };

            // On change son sprite, bug lorsqu'on met un sprite "fixe"
            choosen_musician.set("spriteSheet", "normal_rose");
            if (busy_musican._htOption) {busy_musican._htOption.set_occupe()};

            setTimeout(function(){
                if (has_been_clicked==false) {
                    choosen_musician._htOption.set_normal();
                    //comboCounter=0;
                };
                if (busy_musican._htOption) {busy_musican._htOption.set_normal();};
            },2000);

        }, 2500);


        //On render tout ça
        collie.Renderer.addLayer(layer);
        collie.Renderer.load(document.getElementById("container"));
        collie.Renderer.start();

    </script>
```

I know it's a long example but I need some help..

It's a simple animation sprites with some switch of sprites.

Actually, the game run at 4-6 FPS on my Android tablet and i don't know why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beginning in Android 3.0 (API level 11), the Android 2D rendering pipeline supports hardware acceleration, meaning that all drawing operations that are performed on a View's canvas use the GPU. Because of the increased resources required to enable hardware acceleration, your app will consume more RAM.

In your Android manifest file, add the following attribute to the  tag to enable hardware acceleration for your entire application:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

For detailed information about hardware acceleration visit the following link: [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)